# Xml Linq. A problem with the objects. The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my objects of class XDocument of System.Xml.Linq namespace.

I tried to describe all xml things **in the class TemplateXML.cs (not Main class)** and after of declaring object I can't do nothing with it.

> ERROR was in the last line with xdoc.Save: The name 'xdoc' does not
>   exist in the current context.

After I founded that it is problem only when I create xml objects not in Main class.

Which type of item (obviously not a class) I have to create for describing my code? In my winform application there is just one button for generate xml file and I dont want to place it to Main class cause its huge.

PS I use needed namespace and xml.linq link in references of my project.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).